# No operations defined in spec! && Resolver error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'api')

Tags: node.js, json, swagger-ui

I have this error in my node JS in swagger-ui-express I don`t know how to fix it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2ONj.png)

this is the code in the index.js file

in this code I`am tryin to call the json file that I make and call it swagger.json

```
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express'), swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json')
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument))
```

that the pic of the beggin of the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv1fI.png)

but I`am think that the error is here in this json file

```
"paths": {
    "/api/category": {
        "tages": [
            "Category"
        ],
        "summery": [
            "Get all Categories"
        ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "categoryName",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "description": "Category name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "page",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "description": "Page Number",
                "type": "integer",
                "default": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "PageSize",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "integer",
                "default": 10
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "OK",
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ServiceResponse"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "post": {
        "tages": [
            "Category"
        ],
        "summery": "Create Category API",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "categoryName",
                "in": "formDate",
                "descripition": "Category Name",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "CategoryDescription",
                "in": "formDate",
                "descripition": "Category Description",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "Category Image",
                "in": "formDate",
                "descripition": "Category Image",
                "type": "file"
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "OK",
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ServiceResponse"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some typos and syntax errors:

- The `"/api/category"` path is missing the `"get":` node that would wrap the GET operation definition. It should look like this:

  ```yaml
  "paths": {
    "/api/category": {
      "get": {
        "tags": ...
  ```
- `"tages"` should be `"tags"`.
- `"summery": [...]` should be replaced with:

  ```yaml
  "summary": "Get all Categories",
  ```
- `"in": "formDate"` should be `"in": "formData"` ("a" at the end).
- `"descripition"` should be `"description"`.

Paste your OpenAPI JSON into https://editor.swagger.io - it will show all errors.

Comment: https://editor.swagger.io/   that is all my json is there is any resourc to learn it??

Comment: Check out the guides at https://swagger.io/docs/specification and https://oai.github.io/Documentation/specification.html

Comment: thank you i will try to fix all the errors